# Avoid cartesian join in sparkSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datastax-enterprise

Dataframe A (millions of records) one of the column is create_date,modified_date

Dataframe B 500 records has start_date and end_date

Current approach:

```
Select a.*,b.* from a join b on a.create_date between start_date and end_date
```

The above query performs cartesian product join in sparkSQL and it takes forever to complete.
Can I achieve the same functionality by some other means.
I tried broadcasting the smaller RDD

EDIT:

```
spark version 1.4.1
No. of executors 2
Memmory/executor 5g
No. of cores 5
```

Comment: "I tried broadcasting the smaller RDD" And what happened?

Comment: It is still the same. DAG shows shuffledHashJoin and cartesianProduct

Comment: size of in-memory table A is 140MB and B is 22kb for testing purpose. Input shows 2.2 GB for this particular query in sparkUI

Comment: I doubt join support between clause  in spark as hive does support only equality on join .

Answer (score 0):

You can not avoid Cartesian product as spark sql donot support Non-equi 
[links](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/sql-programming-guide.html)